# Custom Errors in my Website

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

When I am Connecting a website through remote machine, The Website showing the run-time error

**Details**: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

**Notes**: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

But i want to display entire site in my website, and one more thing i am using Ajax controls in website, they are CalenderExtender control.

Only Ajax Control tabs showing errors, remaining will be executed perfectly.

```
enter code here

  <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

     <configuration>
       <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
       </system.web>
     </configuration>


  <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

   <configuration>
     <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
     </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an exception somewhere, it may (or may not) be related to your configuration of the AJAX controls, and you need to correct this first. Check the event log on the server to see the exception details, or just configure your site to expose the details in the browser (which is suggested in the error message you're currently seeing.

You should have only a single `<customErrors>` tag in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Set the mode to "off" if you want the site to display all the exception details. However, on production websites, it's generally recommended never to display these details to users.

Comment: But I am using Ajax CalenderExtender Controls in website, so must and should display those items.

Comment: @Naresh `customErrors` has nothing related to custom controls you are using.

Comment: Ok, I am using .net 4.0  framework, how to view my site in remote machine without having customErrors?

Comment: I found the answer is before posting the website install application pool for asp.net and their version

Comment: Open cmd and type c:\>%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspreg_iis -i